# How to find out why OS X is requesting privilege elevation for an app?

Tags: macos, security

I occasionally see the standard OS dialog stating something like "Application-so-and-so wants to make changes to your system.  Enter Administrator credentials to authorize."

How would I find out exactly what resources the application wants to gain elevated write access to?

Related to that, which process opens that dialog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It is not possible to know at the time the credentials are requested.** The security mechanisms in OS X do not require pre-authorization of specific actions.

Applications and other processes are asking for one or more [authorization rights](https://www.dssw.co.uk/reference/authorization-rights/). Each right grants the application specific capabilities:

> ### [Authorisation Rights](https://www.dssw.co.uk/reference/authorization-rights/)
>
> Authorisation rights are a core part of Mac OS X's security. Rights determine who can and can not access specific functionality. Administrators of Macs often need to change the defaults that ship with Mac OS X.

Use **Console.app** to view the `/var/log/authd.log`. This log file contains every successful and unsuccessful attempt to gain these rights.

If granted, the application is then free to perform actions with this new raised level of authorisation. Occasionally the actions are also logged in the `authd.log` file.

#### User Interface

The process responsible for showing the security user interface is part of OS X and not part of the requesting application. The application is likely in `/System/Library/CoreServices`.

The requesting application does not and can not access the credentials interface.

### Limits of Time, Use, or Both

OS X's rights are often limited by time or use. As an example, the [authenticate-admin-30](https://www.dssw.co.uk/reference/authorization-rights/authenticate-admin-30.html) right is limited to 30 minutes. Other actions are limited to a single use; such as launching an assisting process just once.

As OS X has been developed, Apple have tended towards restricting initial rights. With OS X 10.11, even `root` the once super user has been limited by default. All with the aim of better layering security.

Comment: "Authorization rights" is the search term I needed to keep looking deeper into this.

Comment: Follow up question: I get this dialog we're talking about while I'm logged in with Administrator account already.  I understand that the processes started by a user have the same access level as the user.  Is that true?  If so, how come the system asks to re-authenticate on behalf of apps I started?

Comment: I have extended the answer. I hope this helps.

Comment: In later versions of MacOS, authd has been replaced with Apple System Log. You'll find the log information in /var/log/asl